# How to connect to Gmail using node.js imapflow?

Tags: node.js, gmail, imap, imapflow

I'm using `imapflow` package like this:

```
import config from './config.js';
import { ImapFlow } from 'imapflow';

const client = new ImapFlow({
    host: 'imap.gmail.com',
    port: 993,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'muhemail@gmail.com',
        pass: '123'
    }
});

await client.connect();

console.log('OK');
```

And it throws with `Invalid credentials (Failure)`. I've quadruple-checked that login and password are correct, IMAP is enabled in GMail settings. Less than secure apps aren't enabled though, and I'd prefer to keep it that way. When I try to use the same credentials in Thunderbird, it opens an OAuth login window, which I suppose I should somehow incorporate with imapflow? Or is there a different solution?

Comment: Try using an apps password

Comment: @DaImTo, it's only available for 2FA enabled accs, and I don't have that

Comment: Try using [Xoauth2](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol) then instead of login and password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gmail does not allow accessing its IMAP services by using plain username and password.
You should first get OAuth2.0 credentials via the Gmail api example ([here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs)) and then should convert it to xoauth2.

```
let {installed: {client_id, client_secret}} = require('./client_secret') // the client_secret.json file
let xoauth2gen = xoauth2.createXOAuth2Generator({
  user: '*******', // the email address
  clientId: client_id,
  clientSecret: client_secret,
  refreshToken: refresh_token
 })

xoauth2gen.getToken(function(err, xoauth2token) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err)
  }
        
  let imap = new Imap({
     xoauth2: xoauth2token,
     host: 'imap.gmail.com',
     port: 993,
     tls: true,
     authTimeout: 10000,
     debug: console.log,
 })
```

Comment: So I need to register an app with Google first?

Comment: Probably Google is makeing some changes to less secure apps.  I suspect you are falling into that with this.

Comment: Yes, or turn 2FA on for the account.

Comment: @DaImTo can you explain better how to use 2FA or Credentials ?? Pleas I'm not able to understand the google documentation and how to use with IMAP